# Rollback to older version of svn using Subclipse

Tags: svn, subclipse

Currently I am on revision 21000 and I want to get back to revision 20995 and I want to do it without the need to merge because I have some empty packages that can't be checkout nor added and deleted and I want to return to the state when everything was fine. So how can I do this with Subclipse or TortoiseSVN and if I am able to set the repository to that revision are my the other people that are working on the same project going to encounter any problems if they are all on revisions prior to 20995. Will svn recognize that this is the same information.

Comment: Do you want to see that revision, or undo the previous 5 revisions, so the last revision in the repository is the same as revision 21000? Would creating a branch based upon revision 20995 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via copy, but you might need to delete first so that you are essentially using copy to "replace" the content.  In your case, I would reverse merge the 5 revisions you do not want.  See:

http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/second-chances

It also has some links to other sources and ways to do this.